How to write a gradle plugin to use a Maven mojo
In this Gradle doc page "Migrating Builds From Apache Maven -> Dealing with uncommon and custom plugins", it says the following about reimplementing (to Gradle) Maven plugins that don't use the Maven project object:

you can trivially reimplement it as a custom Gradle task type. Simply define task inputs and outputs that correspond to the mojo parameters and convert the execution logic into a task action.

This sounds great!  I want to use a Maven plugin that happens to derive from AbstractMojo, so I think this is exactly what this text is describing.  (The plugin is here)
But... I can't actually find any documentation or examples of how to "simply" do this.
How do I write a Gradle plugin that will map inputs/outputs to this mojo?  Can I see some example code?

Can you give a more specific example where is the problem?
In gradle docs there is a whole section for creating advanced tasks actions: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_tasks.html#custom_tasks

@Michal I don't see anything on that page that applies to my question.  If it helps, I've added a link to the plugin that I want to adapt.

IMHO using gradle it should look like this (more or less): https://0bin.net/paste/jU9Pgoej#ZfcGdKp2eqEjugYMkEFUNuY+GUYM9jSlBwkGcBeSvQk

Thank you, I'll see what I can do with that!
